# Html Text Editor problem

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Hii,

I m using a simple HTML Text editor by providig 'contentEditable' property of a div to true. All the formatting operations are working fine. The problem is when i copy and paste some html contents from somewhere else and try to post to DB the entire content may not post in to db because of the size limitation of the column. Is there any solution regarding this? **I m using sql server 2008**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What DB are you running?

The only solution to that is to choose a field type and size that's appropriate for the data you are going to be storing there; or if you can't do that save the contents in a file and store the file location in the DB.